# Python module organization for a pythonic import

Tags: python, module

I have a module called `module_name`, organized in such a way that I have a folder called `module_name`, containing `__init__.py`, and `module_name.py`. To import the functions within `module_name.py`, I have to do the following:

```
import module_name.module_name

# call the function
x = module_name.module_name.fnc()
```

Is there a way for me to edit the `__init__.py` such that the following works?

```
import module_name

# call the function
x = module_name.fnc()
```

It would be helpful if the answer could help with cases where `module_name` and `module_name.py` have different names, say `module_name` and `submodule_name.py`.

Comment: Add `from .module_name import fnc` to `__init__.py`

Comment: @MYousefi Would I have to do this for all the functions in `module_name.py`?

Comment: You can use `import *` to import everything

Comment: Just a note `import *` will import everything that is visible including any module level variables. Also, the directory with `__init__.py` is called the package and `module_name.py` is what is called a module within the package. A package only knows of what has been defined within `__init__.py`